# Are these window trim strips purely decorative? If not, how to replace them?

Tags: windows, trim, window-frame

Do these window trim strips (shown pulling up from the metal frame) perform any useful function, or are they purely decorative?

[image]

If functional, how to replace them?

Comment: It is some sort of either seal or weatherstripping - definitely not decorative. The question is whether it is a must for the windows (i.e., without it, the glass might be loose) or if it is purely to help stop heat loss. Hopefully someone who knows windows better (I know Windows fairly well, but not windows) will have a definitive answer.

Comment: If you are talking about the black rubber pieces, they are weatherstripping/sealing pieces.  Quite functional, but might just need to be glue back down or replaced.

Comment: Are those black rubber pieces between two panes of glass, or are they just on the inside of the window?

Comment: @SteveSh they are on the outside of the window (the blinds in the picture are on the inside) and are made of some kind of fairly stiff plastic, not rubber.

Comment: Then like crip659 said, they're weather stripping material used to 1) maybe hold the window pane in place (like old fashioned window glazing) and 2) seal the window to keep rain/moisture out.

Answer (score 3):

These strips are not for decoration. When the windows are new, they fit into the groove very tight and help to secure the glass after the window caulking/sealer has been applied between the aluminum frame and glass. They also keep water and dirt from filling up the groove and provide some weather stripping although the caulking/sealant usually does that. I have seen glass fall out of the frame when stripping like this has been rempved and not replaced. If it's still pliable, clean it off with soap and water and wedge it back into the frame like the right side of your picture shows. If it's dried out, cut a pieces so you can match the profile  at your home / window store or the internet  and re-install.

Comment: As jack advised above, clean and reinstall, but if you need to get them new try the local hardware store. I find the local stores, ( not big box) often stock things that are indigenous to the homes nearby, that can't be found in other stores.

Comment: Do you happen to know what they are called? It would really help with finding replacements.

Comment: Try “glazing spline” or “glazing gasket”, and look first at CRL. (Not sure crl sells to the public, but I’m sure you can find a sympathetic glass place.)

Comment: also be careful not to stretch it while installing else it will shrink over time.